# Adding values in an array in function

Tags: android, arrays

So I have a firebase database having quantity of different items sold. I want to extract those quantity and put them in an Array and then calculate total items sold. This is the code I'm trying but for some reason it's not putting values in the array.

Code :

```
for (int i=101;i<7000;i++) {

    String id = String.valueOf(i);


    firebase2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shops").child(shopname).child("Items Sold");

    firebase2.child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String qt = dataSnapshot.child("quantity").getValue().toString();
                int quant = Integer.parseInt(qt);

                Total[j] = quant;
                j++;

                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(quant));
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(Total[j]));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

Logcat:

```
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 110
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 0
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 38
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 0
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 31
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 0
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 50
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 0
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 1
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 0
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 1
2020-06-09 21:08:21.746 11035-11035/com.example.adminapp D/error: 0
```

as you can see all the values after the quantity show up as 0 where as they should come same as the quantity. Please help me...

Comment: You increment `j` after using it to store `quant` - just move increment after log.

Comment: What is j anyway, not declared anywhere.

Comment: j is basically int initialized as 0